# When getting the canvas data from the background page, how to draw it on the Window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've created a new window in the background page. On the window's page, there is a canvas. The image data to draw on the canvas is got by the background page too. I'm wondering how could I put the image data in the Window's canvas? Do I have to pass the data to the content script?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to access the document of the newly created window from the background page. Following is the code snippet:

```js
chrome.app.window.create('XXX.html', {
 id: id,
        outerBounds: {
     top: top,
     left: left,
     width: width,
     height: height
 },
 frame: 'none'
}, function(wnd) {
 wnd.outerBounds.setPosition(left, top);

 var doc = wnd.contentWindow.document;
 doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     canvas = doc.getElementById('canvas');
             
     canvas.width = width;
     canvas.height = height;

     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use putImageData() method to put image data in the windows canvas. Also, use  drawImage() method to draw it on the window. To ensure that the image has been loaded, you can call drawImage() from window.onload() or from document.getElementById("imageID").onload.

Here's a code snippet for putImageData() method:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

function copy() {
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(10, 10, 50, 50);
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 70);
}
```

Here's a code snippet for drawImage() method:

```
window.onload = function() {
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
};
```

Here are the link's were I found the solution:

Draw Image:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Put Image data:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_putimagedata.asp

Comment: Thanks, datul. I know how to draw an image on the canvas. Here, what I'm concerned about is how to got the document of the newly created window from the background page. I've figured it out by myself.